# How To Compare the Local/Current Time To a Specified In a Tuple/String Time

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am a newbie to programming and Python, please forgive my ignorance. 
I'm trying to write a script which pulls data from the 'crontab' list on a RHEL machine and checks whether a certain process run at required certain date and time (which is the time in 'crontab' of the run user).

I have the run date and time in a string of the process - it is like:

> "Fri Dec 23 16:20:39 2016"

How can I compare whether this time which is a string (consists of empty space and ":" between the columns) has surpassed the current local time on the RHEL machine?

I've found that it is enough just to check the hour (the minutes and seconds do not matter) so I'm thinking about:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
strftime("%H %d %m %Y", gmtime())
```

Which returns:

> '18 08 01 2017'

In other words, is there a way to convert a simple tuple/string into time which Python can use in order to compare it with another time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the module datetime and the function strptime:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Here's an example script which does what you want:

```
import datetime as dt

def datestamp_after_current_time(datetime_str):

     datetime_ = dt.datetime.strptime(datetime_str, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

     return datetime_ > dt.datetime.now()


datetime_str = 'Fri Dec 23 16:20:39 2016'

datestamp_after_current_time(datetime_str)
```

Alternatively, if your timestamp is in UTC, then instead of datetime.now() in the last line, use datetime.utcnow().

Comment: Python is amazing! I'm grateful, thank you, David! Didn't put some thoughts that I might have also needed a function, really nice, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could be of help! Please do accept the answer, it would be much appreciated ;P.

Comment: Done! Thank you! I would like to say that the solution of MattDMo also does a very good job.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `strptime()` *or* `strftime()` for this - you just need [`python-dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/):

```
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse

datetime_str = "Fri Dec 23 16:20:39 2016"
print(parse(datetime_str) < datetime.datetime.now())
# prints "True", meaning that datetime_str is in the past
```

Comment: Thank you, that's also a very nice solution, MattDMo!
I just also needed to run these Shell commands:
   51  curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
   52  python get-pip.py
   53  pip -V
   54  pip install python-dateutil